# Cannot inspect Self in method while debugging

Tags: objective-c, debugging

I have a method on one of my ViewController's that is called by one of its view's and delivered some value.  It then sends out a message to a manager object with some information about the VC's state.

```
- (void)elementXChangedWithValue:(float)value {

   ParameterManager * pMan = [ParameterManager sharedInstance];
   [pMan updateParameter:self.elementX.parameter value:value];

}
```

In debugging, it was important for me to inspect what the `.SomeElement.parameter` state was so I could know what was getting lost in translation by the time I get to my `ParameterManager`.

Unfortunately, although Self is definitely non-nil and accessible the debugger shows scant information about the class making quick and practical glancing of the value difficult.  (i will sometimes invoke "po" command in the debugger command line, however).

Not sure if it helps but this project is running heavy with the Objective-C/Swift interoperability although the ViewController is a fully Objective-C class.

Here is an image of what I am getting in the debugger.  The drop-down arrow shows nothing but empty.
[image: debugger]

Comment: Can't you get it with " po self.elementX.parameter " or NSLog() or print() ?

Answer (score 1):

The debugger isn't perfect and sometimes you just cant see what is in certain areas, such as self.  What does always work is NSLog's placed in code though, so if all else fails, add one of those in at the right place to print out the object you wish to know about.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger may show more info after you make it execute these commands:

```
expr @import UIKit;
expr @import Foundation;
```

This loads the whole UIKit and Foundation symbols in the debugger at runtime, you only need to execute it once per debug session.

You can automate this with a user-defined breakpoint that'll be triggered every time your application starts in the debugger.

Source : http://furbo.org/2015/05/11/an-import-ant-change-in-xcode/

Comment: thanks, i did not know about this.  however, in my circumstance I wonder why self is missing.  In all other methods i've looked at in debug (millions), there's always at least some symbols in self when i drop down the arrow.  why should this one not have anything.  It definitely has properties.